# After Installation of Yosemite some command line tools not found!

Tags: terminal

I just did a clean installation of 10.10. 
Now some command line tools won't work anymore.
In example `gshred` is not found anymore (always worked on Lion) and `man gpg` gives
"No manual entry for gpg".

Has anyone an idea what the problem might be? :)

Comment: Did you have installed homebrew or something like that? Did you looking to command `shred`? Not sure, but I think `gpg` is not part of OSX.

Comment: gpg and shred are not part of OS X so how did you install them

Answer (score 1):

GPG for Mac can be found at:
https://gpgtools.org/

Your problem description also means, if not using some PKI infrastructure, you lost your PGP keys...

Comment: The keys might not have been lost as they would be in your home directory

Comment: You are right if you made an upgrade not a fresh Yosemite installation from an USB stick with erasing the HD. :)